# разница между http и https в словаре прокси

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy, requests

Всем привет! Возник вопрос: в документации к requests указано, что нужно явно указывать какие это прокси (http или https) :

```
'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128',
'https': 'http://10.10.1.10:1080',
```

можно ли везде указывать например только http? будет ли прокси работать вот так:

```
'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128',
'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:1080',
```

ведь чаще всего в базе прокси все намешано- и http и https, и к каждой уточнять- неудобно.

Comment: начнем с того, что технически одну и ту же схему вы указать не сможете, так как в словаре не может быть одинаковых ключей. И если вы укажете http, а сервер будет требовать https, то конечно же ничего не заработает

Comment: Наверное, для `'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128',
'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:1080',` будет такое в словаре: `{'http':['http://10.10.1.10:3128', 'http://10.10.1.10:1080'],}`

Comment: @rusnasonov все, туплю, это же просто ключи, а прокси всегда указываются http, вспасибо!

Comment: @gil9red обратиться можно по ключу так: http[1],http[2] верно?

Comment: > {'http':['http://10.10.1.10:3128', 'http://10.10.1.10:1080'], } < requests так не умеет, и непонятно что вы этим хотите сказать. Если не получилось сходить на одну прокси, идти на вторую? Схему нужно указывать, чтобы в зависимости от схемы в запросе requests выбрал нужную прокси. > и к каждой уточнять- неудобно. < А как requests узнает где у вас http, а где https, он же не оракул.

Comment: Для того словаря: `d = {'http':['http://10.10.1.10:3128', 'http://10.10.1.10:1080'],}`: `d['http'][0]`, `d['http'][1]`. Если у вас список прокси, тогда перед каждым запросом можно из списка брать случайную и по ней идти, т.к. похоже `requests` не умеет с списком прокси работать

Answer (score 1):

Можно, но тогда сайт, работающий только с https, проигнорирует все Ваши http. Так что, лучше указывать и http, и https.